# android layout set ten squares with fixed margin

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a layout which contains 10 squares, that fills the width of the screen
with fixed margin between them.
You can see the sketch attached.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

[image: Example Sketch]

Thanks!

Comment: what are in the squares? are these views too? Are they ImageViews perhaps?

Comment: How many rows of squares do you have?

Comment: The squares are images. There will be one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap each square in either a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, setting the `layout_width` to 0dp and the `layout_weight` to 1 (or any value, really, as long as each has the SAME value), then use a horizontal `LinearLayout` to wrap all of it.

EDIT: Actually the inner LinearLayout/RelativeLayouts shouldn't be necessary as long as you use the src field of the ImageView, not background.

Answer (score 0):

TableLayout should work fine.  Often used for calculator board which is essentially rows of squares. Try it and let us know.